# Rotate UIImage?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Can you rotate a `UIImage` without using a transform on `UIImageView`. I'm using a `UIImage` as a custom pin on a map and would like to rotate it if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The only thing you *might* be able to do is to set the UIImageOrientation to coheres the OS into rotating it for you on the basis of that - though that will only give you the four (main) 90-degree rotations.

Answer (score 0):

yess you can rotate and UIImage in predefined ImageOrientations:

UIImage *rotatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageObject.CGImage   scale:imageObject.scale   orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

here orientation is predefined enum variable:

```
UIImageOrientationUp,
UIImageOrientationUpMirrored
UIImageOrientationDown
UIImageOrientationDownMirrored
UIImageOrientationLeft
UIImageOrientationRight    etc
```

it rotates UIImage.